# memory error while export data in excel file

Tags: php, codeigniter

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32 bytes) in `/home/studentlms/public_html/application/third_party/PHPExcel/Cell.php` on line 146 while export data from database

Comment: Just add this line in your index.php
`ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');`

Comment: ok, i try it. thank you for suggession

Comment: ok , let us know if still you get some problem...

Answer (score 0):

You need to increase "memory_limit" configuration in PHP.INI file

Refer: http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit

or

You can set it at run time using ini_set() function as

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '512M');
```

or

You can set it to infinite value as

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
```